# postgres SELECT query returns unusable result

Tags: node.js, json, postgresql, select, pg-promise

I have a simple SELECT query that is returning an unusable result. I am using pg-promise in node.js

```
[
  {
    "function_name": "(f10d1988-4db5-49de-97ab-0c8b15bedfa7,image.jpg,Image)"
  },
  {
    "function_name": "(f10d1988-4db5-49de-97ab-0c8b15bedfa7,image2.jpg,Image 2)"
  }
]
```

but I was expecting a basic json structure like

```
[
  {
    id: '',
    title: '',
    image: ''
  },
  {...etc}
]
```

Why is it doing this? How do I get a normalized result?

My query looks like the below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_photos(
  title_param     TEXT
)
RETURNS TABLE(
  id         UUID,
  image      varchar(200),
  title      varchar(200) 
) AS
$func$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT
    i.id,
    i.image,
    i.title
  FROM images AS i
  WHERE i.title = title_param;
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Here is my db conenctor setup, almost all defaults.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const pg = require('pg-promise')({
  promiseLib: Promise
});

const config = {
  user: process.env.USER,
  host: process.env.HOST,
  database: process.env.DATABASE,
  password: process.env.PASSWORD
};

const db = pg(config);

export default db;
```

Here is the express endpoint that is calling the function:

```
export const getData = async (req, res) => {
  const { title } = req.query;
  let data;
  try {
    data = await db.many('SELECT function_name($1)', [title]);
  } catch (err) {
    data = err;
  }
  res.send(data);
};
```

EDIT

I ran the query manually instead of through a function and the data returned correctly which means that there is an issue with my TABLE() return. What could possibly cause this issue?

```
images = await db.many(`
  SELECT
    p.id,
    p.img,
    p.type,
    p.title
  FROM photos p
  WHERE p.type = '${type}';
`, [type]);
```

Comment: Kindly post your js code, where you are catching the results.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth I added the db js and endpoint, mostly defaults

Comment: Just try res.send(data[0]); https://www.codota.com/code/javascript/functions/pg/Client/query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [func](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#func) as the query method:

```
data = await db.func('function_name', [title]);
```

It assumes you return a table, and so will work for you by default.

And for stored procedures, there's [proc](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#proc) method.

---

Also, your parameter formatting for the images query is wrong, see [Named Parameters](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#named-parameters):

> **IMPORTANT**: Never use the reserved `${}` syntax inside ES6 template strings ...

Comment: I tried the above but received the following error
`error: function function_name($1)(unknown) does not exist` but keeping the function as `db.many(SELECT * FROM function_name(...etc))` works fine

also, interesting that ${} shouldn't be used but worked in this simple case, still good to see the best practice as a reference

Comment: @Brandon It looks like you didn't pass it the expected parameters correctly, or there is no `function_name` function defined. You should include the code that you actually executed here. b.t.w. I am the author of `pg-promise`, and the solution I gave is the right way to do it.

Comment: I tried again, the issue is that I kepy `function_name($1)` when using `db.func` instead of just `function_name`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Because the function is defined as returning a table, you need to use it like a table:

```
SELECT * FROM function_name($1)
```